# How to listen to Microsoft Media Stream (mms) on Android?

Tags: streaming, internet-radio

There are many radio stations which stream in mms:// like a Chuvash radio: mms://media.cap.ru/ChuvRadio

Is it possible to listen to in on Android?

Comment: From what I recall, *mms://* is actually a predefined content provider in Android for Multimedia Messages. It would be different under Android to handle the streaming of radio - perhaps *rtsp://* protocol... just saying :)

Answer (score 1):

I know TuneIn can play MMS radio, but from what I see, only ones from a predefined set. ChuvRadio doesn't seem to be there yet. Maybe you can submit your station to them?

Answer (score 1):

Try [yxPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=kr.mobilesoft.yxplayer). Unlike other apps, it allows a user to enter custom streaming URLs from what I can see.

There's also [vPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t) that might work.

Comment: Thank you it works, but I must have it open. I neither can do anything else.

Comment: have you tried pressing HOME instead of back while it's streaming? Ordinarily, that ought to "minimise" an app rather than exit.

Comment: Yes I tried that, too. :(

Answer (score 1):

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) also supports mms streams, and it's great because you can minimise the application and keep listening to the radio, as I am right now.